# OpenNLP - Model version 1.6.0 not supported by this (1.5.3) version of OpenNLP

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am currently trying to use a custom-trained OpenNLP Name Finder model in code. My project uses OpenNLP 1.6.0 and is developed using Eclipse IDE. The model was also trained using OpenNLP 1.6.0.

However, I'm getting this annoying error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: Model version 1.6.0 is not supported by this (1.5.3) version of OpenNLP!
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250241/why-is-a-self-trained-ner-model-incompatible-with-the-version-of-opennlp) and the answer stated that the problem was due to the OpenNLP model being trained using the same version as the one in use (i.e. training a model using 1.6.0 and using it in a project that also uses 1.6.0). However I also have other Java projects using OpenNLP 1.6.0, and they were able to load the model successfully, so I don't think this applies to me.

The *.classpath* of my project also shows that the project is referencing the OpenNLP 1.6.0 libraries.

I know the question is rather vague, but if anyone has any insight into why this could be happening, please let me know!

***To sum up: Unable to load custom trained OpenNLP Name Finder model in code due to apparent OpenNLP version incompatibility. Model was trained in OpenNLP 1.6.0, which my project also uses. Other projects also using 1.6.0 were able to load the model successfully.***

Answer (score 0):

I've pinpointed the source of my error - my project was making use of the Apache Tika 1.13 library as well, which contains its own implementation of OpenNLP 1.5.3.

As a result the classpath contained multiple JARs that contain their own versions of the OpenNLP classes.

**EDIT 16/1/2017: From my findings, the order in which the libraries are loaded matters.**

**Please correct me if I am wrong here: in Java (and other languages as well), once a dependency component has been loaded in memory, then by default, it will not be loaded again even if another version is required later.**

**Because of this, if the Tika library is loaded before the OpenNLP 1.6.0 libraries, OpenNLP 1.5.3 will be loaded first, and the program will "stick" to 1.5.3 in spite of the subsequent loading of 1.6.0. Similarly, if the reverse happens (1.6.0 is loaded before Tika), the program will "stick" to 1.6.0 instead.**